# Integrate telegram bot with AWS Cogntio?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

The main idea is to register a user in Cognito User Pool (I'm thinking about how to implement a sign-up process inside the Telegram app), that in the future he could sign in throw the web?

I already know about [contact object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact), so, I would prefer to use a phone number instead of username/email on the web.

So, the main problem I guess is the setting password process? (If I wanna leave it to the Telegram bot).

All of your ideas are welcome:)

Comment: Maybe, it'll not be bad to use Cognito MFA for generating temp password and send it to a user by sms for example? Does Cognito allow to login only by MFA without password?

Comment: Seems like Cognito requires password.

Comment: Just leave a note here:
maybe [login widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) can help with implementation

Comment: Add a note here:
`Telegram Login Widget` realizes `OAuth` protocol.